# Micropython - maximal decimal number (esp32)?

Tags: esp32, micropython

Can the accuracy of the decimal number be increased to 6 digits ? eg: 50.820257

```
print(50.12025733333333)
50.82025
```

I need this to read gps coordinates....

Comment: What GPS are you using and does your GPS support that level of precision?
A look at the data sheet would be the place to start.

Answer (score 1):

You can access more of the float by formatting it as follows:

```
Entering REPL. Use Control-X to exit.
>
MicroPython v1.12-452-g801f7dca7 on 2020-05-14; TinyPICO with ESP32-PICO-D4
Type "help()" for more information.
>>> 
>>> x = 12.123456789
>>> type(x)
<class 'float'>
>>> print(x)
12.12346
>>> print('{:.6f}'.format(x))
12.123458
```

If you're going to log the lat\lon in a file and not do math with it that should get you there.

There is a more general discussion on Float Precision in GitHub: https://github.com/micropython/micropython/issues/4380